# Replacing a wall outlet with three black and three white wires with a smart outlet with one white and one black wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I got a Kasa Smart WI-Fi Power Outlet for Christmas and want to replace an outlet in my living room with this. The Smart Outlet has one White, one Black and one Green wire coming out of it and no other places to connect wires.  When I pulled the outlet out from the wall, there were three black, three white and a copper wire connected to it. What is the reason for three wires?

Based on  my research I should tie all three black and all three white wires into a pigtail with the wire from the smart outlet and wire nut them together, then do the copper to the green. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Answer (score 1):

If your existing blacks were all on 1 side of the receptacle on the brass screw and the whites on the other side silver screw than yes you can tie them together.

Why 3 cables , possibly 1 feeder the one that supplies power , one going to the next receptacle and one feeding a light switch. This would be quite common.
I would say possibly every house I have wired has at least one or 2 of these configurations.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The black is all on one side and white on the other so I'll tie them together. As for a light switch, I dont think there is one for that outlet, but I'll have to double check now. Thanks again

Comment: You can add a short piece of wire out of the pigtail to connect the outlet. I pigtail most of the time.